# File.list and File.listFiles return NULL

Tags: android, file

in my app, the user can download different sound files. I use the downloadManager for this and everything is working fine here.

```
String url = localList.get(position).guid;
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setDescription(localList.get(position).title);
request.setTitle("Downloading Podcast");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.
    VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
}


request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/MyAudio/",
localList.get(position).title + ".mp3");

DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)
v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

The problem is, when i try to show all files in the directory with file.list or file.listfiles its returning NULL.

```
File f = new File("/MyAudio/");
File file[] = f.listFiles();
String filename[] = f.list();
```

I tried a lot of stuff, like changing the folder name and location, using request.setDestinationInExternalFileDir , writing and reading the folder with

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String folder = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAudio" ;
```

But nothing helped so far. I always get NULL returned by file.listFiles.

I use these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

which should cover everything i need.

One last point: I write the file in an arrayadapter class and try to read the folder from my mainactivity, and i see the folder and files on my phone, so im sure they exist.

Thx in advance

Comment: What is path on sdcard?

Comment: File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String folder = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAudio" ;
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(),folder, localList.get(position).title + ".mp3");     PATH IS /storage/emulated/0/MyAudio @sandy

Comment: Ok, fixed it. THe problem was, setDestinationInExternalFilesDir points to android/data/***/files already, so when i give it an absolut path it creates the tree again in that folder and i cant read it with the normal path in getExternalFilesDir. request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(),null,
localList.get(position).title + ".mp3"); for the donwloadmanager and getExternalFilesDir(null); for reading does what i needed